# multi level type inheritance, x inherits from y inherits from z

Tags: pddl

in PDDL I can define "sub" types like this:

```
(:types
  one two - parent other
)
```

`one` and `two` are also `parent`, `other` is distinct.

So like, the predicate `(both ?x - parent)` accepts `one`s and `two`s.

I want to do multi-level inheritance, I tried

```
(:types
  sprite fanta - fizzy water - drink
  food
)
```

I want `sprite` and `fanta` to be `fizzy`, and `fizzy` and `water` are both of the type `drink`.

So my predicate `(pour ?x - drink)` should accept `sprite`, but at the moment it doesn't.

How do I correctly set up this type tree?

```
object
├── drink
│   ├── fizzy
│   │   ├── fanta
│   │   └── sprite
│   └── water
└── food
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late to answer your question.
This code should do what you want:

```
(:types
   food drink - object
   water fizzy - drink
   fanta sprite - fizzy)
```

Hope it helped! You can find a whole PDDL reference [here](https://nergmada.github.io/pddl-reference/).

Comment: The link is dead.